# convert string from getString to getBytes in android studio

Tags: android, bluetooth, qr-code

i want to create an app that can scan qr code to a text and send it through bluetooth, so i have to create the program that can pass my text (string) into another activity(bluetooth activity). the problem is in my second activity i had to use ouputStream (getBytes) which can cause java.lang.NullPointerException. can you give me some idea how to convert string that i got from getString so i can use getBytes?

This is my program in my second activity (Bluetooth.java)

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    out.append("\n...In onResume...\n...Attempting client connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.
    try {
        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
        out.append("\n...Connection established and data link opened...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    out.append("\n...Sending message to server...");

    try {
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("scanContent");
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
    try {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
        if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
            msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 37 in the java code";
        msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

        AlertBox("Fatal Error", msg);
    }
}
```

and here is my program in my main activity :

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult =   IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        contentTxt.setText(scanContent);

        Intent pass_data = new Intent(this,Bluetooth.class);

        pass_data.putExtra("scanContent",scanContent);
        startActivity(pass_data);

    } else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your log?

Comment: The output stream will be returned even if the socket is not yet connected, but operations on that stream will throw Exception until the associated socket is connected.

Comment: Before writing to socket you should call isConnected() which will return true only if there is an active connection with remote device.

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand :( do i have to create another class (isConnected()) then call it? but i already establish connection before writing socket @NullPointer

Comment: if(btsocket.isConnected()) {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
     }